# JSAPI 2.8 and Dojotoolkit 1.7.2? May?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I realize no one can give a definitive answer but is it reasonable to think the next release of ESRI JSAPI will be built on top of dojotookit 1.7?  And will be released in the next 2-3 months?  Any documention for preparing 1.6 code for the move to 1.7 that takes advantage of some of the loader features introduced in 1.6?

Comment: Regarding docs or advice on moving to 1.7.x's AMD loader, we will not be publishing much in the near future. The reason is that the pre-AMD style of module loading is still fully supported at 1.7.x. Using AMD is recommended, but definitely optional. We plan to gradually add documentation and examples on using our API with an AMD style loader but won't fully move there until dojo is AMD and AMD only (which is slated for dojo's 2.0 release).

Comment: Also, are there any specific dojo 1.7 features you want that are not currently in 1.6?

Comment: Ideally dtk 1.7.2 would be available via the JSAPI...I've committed to the define+require+declare methodology and cannot really justify loading both.  I'm having no issues with the loader...what are the issues you're seeing?  Any active tickets?  See [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8xk3UL1d) for a trial-and-error approach to DKT 1.7.1 + JSAPI 2.7 integration which seems to be working great (for me).

Comment: Here's link to non-closed loader tickets:
http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=open&status=pending&status=reopened&component=Loader&col=id&col=summary&col=component&col=status&col=owner&col=type&col=priority&report=142&order=priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on the JS API team, and while I still can't provide a definitive answer for dojo 1.7.x support, it's probably not going to be in 2.8. We're still working with the dojo team to resolve some issues related to the new loader. This has taken longer than anyone expected but we will get there. Apologies for the delays.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are trying to get 2.8 out for the Dev Summit...

"We'll try, but it's too early to give a guarantee. We're pushing to get 2.8 out for the dev summit. "

-reference (answer #4): [link](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/51686-Multiple-Time-Sliders-on-Same-Page.-Bug)

Summit is March 26-29th ... [summit](http://www.esri.com/events/devsummit/index.html)

Comment: Didn't mention if it would be built on dojotoolkit 1.7 but good to have the rough date.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't program with ESRI JS API but I'm a usual Dojo programmer.
Dojo 1.7 is almost backward compatible with 1.6 It has many improvements and bugfixes.

The most notable change is the way you create widget and also how do you import then with the "require" sentece.
Anyway you can continue working like in a 1.6 way, it is not stricktly necessary to change the way to 1.7

Comment: Yes, dojo 1.* is "future-proof" but I'm looking for documentation indicating how much 1.7-like code I can write against dojo 1.6.1.